# Iterate through Array of String

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I'm trying to store data from `api` to `string array` in `angular5` and use each of the strings as `img src` but i don't think i'm getting it right. I'm currently doing it this way:

**component.ts**

```
let allOther_images: string[] = [];
 data.other_images.forEach(item => {
 allOther_images.push(item.image);
 console.log(allOther_images);
 ["http://web.apiendpoint.com/media/products/dhjsh_HA3PAf1.png"] //console output
})
```

**component.html**

```
<div class="other-images" style="padding: 20px">
 <div class="item" *ngFor="let item of allOther_images">
  <img [src]="item" alt="" style="height: 250px;">
  <span class="remove-img">&times;</span>
 </div>
</div>
```

With this even the image element does not show in `console` so I'm guessing I have the `*ngFor` quite wrong.
Can you spot where I have gone wrong?

Comment: could you provide more details about your code?
I think you should remove the `let` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare **`allOther_images`** globally,

```
allOther_images: string[] = [];
```

and assign the values within your response,

```
data.other_images.forEach(item => {
 allOther_images.push(item.image);
})
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hwzfyw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**